# postfix : How to keep the bcc recipient in email enveloppe

Tags: postfix

By default, postfix is removing the bcc recipient before to pass the mail to the delivery queue. How can you set up postfix to keep the bcc recipient information or add an email header to keep it before the delivery?

We would like to use this feature in the context of a catchall mailbox to know witch recipient has received the mail.

Of course, we can track the information with the postfix queue-id in the maillog but it should be more easy to have it directly in the mail header....

We are runing postfix 2.2.10 and the delivery is dovecot 1.1.2.

Thanks in advance for any hint or solution...

BR

Christin

Comment: Remove the “B” from the “BCC” header and it automagically works :)

Comment: Doesn't that really defeat the purpose of the Bcc: property that users would expect? I.E. Blind Carbon Copy?

Comment: My question is, may be, not clear enough. My question is "How a user can know to wich recipent the mail has been send in his own mailbox?" . This is the purpuse of the header the X-original-to. Of Course, if other BCC are present, these other recipient will not be shown in the X-original-to. So the BCC meaning is therefore kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a delivery with dovecot, you need to add the "O" flag for pipe

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}

Answer (score 0):

Postfix should add X-Original-To: on final delivery because the whole point of **B** lind **CC** is that it is removed.

Comment: Hi Ek,

Thanks for the hint. You are fully right with virtual delivery agent of postfix but not with dovecot. See my own answer ;-)